# cx_Freeze + curses: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'

Tags: python, cx-freeze, curses

I've generated an `exe` file with the [cx_Freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) utility from the following python script:

```
from curses import wrapper

def main(stdscr):
    pass

wrapper(main)
```

But when I'm running it, it gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

Full error:

[image: Error message]

*The thing is that the exe works without errors when I'm excluding `wrapper(main)` from the script.*

Comment: sounds like a limitation of cx_freeze (`fileno` is a standard C runtime function).

Comment: Could you please share your setup script? On which (Windows) platform do you work, how did you get `curses` to work on it (the `curses` module included in the standard Python installation does not work on Windows 7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can produce a working executable from your `curses_example.py` python script using python 3.6 and `cx_Freeze` 5.1.1 on Windows 7 with the following setup script:

```py
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

executables = [Executable('curses_example.py')]

setup(name='curses_example',
      version='0.1',
      description='Sample cx_Freeze script',
      executables=executables)
```

To get `curses` to work, I first needed to install `windows-curses` using

```
pip install windows-curses
```

following a hint from [ImportError: No module named '_curses' when trying to import blessings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35850362/8516269).